# NEXUS S (t-mobile version) 2.3.4 / GRJ22 -- IS ROOT POSSIBLE?? can't mount /system mount /data

Tags: rooting, samsung-nexus-s, t-mobile

I have the Nexus S (t-mobile version) that is 2.3.4 / GRJ22 and just wanted to ask, is root actually possible now??  I see lots of posts about how to do it under 2.3.3, but all the posts I have seen so far mention doing a mount /System mount /data and these ARE NOT options on the bootloader screen under GRJ22.

(these instructions do NOT work:
http://www.techwhizz.com/root-google-nexus-s-android-2-3-4-gingerbread-grj22/
)

Am I totally missing something here?  I'm usually pretty good at figuring this stuff out, but I am at a total loss here and any help would be very much appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How can I root my Nexus S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/16575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this tutorial, http://theunlockr.com/2010/12/17/how-to-root-the-samsung-nexus-s/

Comment: Thank you!  That looks like it will work.  I will report back how it turns out.

Comment: Unfortunately I fall into the group of OS X users who find nothing when they type $ adb devices   I did verify of course that I have USB debugging checked on the phone.  I tried restarting the adb server, the phone, the computer, all to no avail.  Will try with Linux in the next few days, hopefully that will work better.

Answer (score 2):

The Nexus S is a developer phone, so yes it can be rooted **by unlocking the boot-loader** first. That always work.

However, many users wishes to root the phone **without** unlocking the boot-loader. And that is currently (18.06.2011) not possible with Version **2.3.4**. Not with the Nexus-One, not with the Nexus-S.

If you decide to unlock then  Lie Ryan answer shows you how.